# Iterate multiple properties ARM Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

I'm creating an ARM template for a Data Factory. In a pipeline I have two activities for each dataset: one copy, one delete. I have a defined array of datasets.

```
"variables": {
   "datasets": ["foo", "bar", "boo", "far"]
 }
```

I know activities are **properties** and that you can iterate through properties, per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties), but it seems I can only do this for one activity.

For example I would like to do the following with the pipeline template:

```
{
  "name": "MyPipeline",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "activites",
            "count": "[length(variables('datasets'))]",
            "input": {
                "name": "[concat('Copy ', variables('datasets')[copyIndex()])]",
                "type": "Copy"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "activites",
            "count": "[length(variables('datasets'))]",
            "input": {
                "name": "[concat('Delete ', variables('datasets')[copyIndex()])]",
                "type": "Delete"
            }
        },
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally this would produce a pipeline that had the following activities:

- Copy foo, Delete foo
- Copy bar, Delete bar
- Copy boo, Delete boo
- Copy far, Delete far

This, of course, does not work because I cannot have two properties of the same name, "activities". I also cannot set the copy input to both activities because it makes the JSON malformed.

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do it - essentially just iterate over your array twice by duplicating it...  here's one way:

```
    "variables": {
        "datasets": ["foo", "bar", "boo", "far"],
        "bigDataset": "[concat(variables('datasets'), variables('datasets'))]",
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "activities",
                "count": "[length(variables('bigDataset'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[concat(if(less(copyIndex('activities'), length(variables('datasets'))), 'Copy', 'Delete'), variables('bigDataset')[copyIndex('activities')])]",
                    "type": "[if(less(copyIndex('activities'), length(variables('datasets'))), 'Copy', 'Delete')]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

And then on your resource just do:

```
"properties": {
  "activities": "[variables('activities')]",
  ...
}
```

That help?

Comment: Variables was how I had to do it! Thanks!

Comment: you could do it all inline too but vars might be easier to read the resource definition...